# Unable to join and authenticate ubuntu server with AD domain

Tags: permissions, authentication, active-directory, sssd

We have followed up with the steps in the below ubuntu site to configure and join ubuntu server with windows AD domain.
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd-ad
Post completion of steps we are able to see AD id on Ubuntu server but while we are login with credentials its now working and giving permission denied error.

Need some help and guidance if anyone has come across similar issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.